# How to find "/*" in LESS?

Tags: linux, git, less-unix

When I do `git diff HEAD^!` (to diff changes in the `HEAD` commit), output is piped to `LESS`. I need to search the contents of the diff for `/*` (start of C-style comment). I haven't been able to get this working. I hit the forward-slash key on my keyboard to begin searching. I've tried:

```
//*
//\*
/\/\*
```

None of these work (first `/` is to initiate search mode in `LESS`).

Comment: `[/][*]` is one easy approach -- single-character classes have the advantage of being hard to misinterpret and safe against unescaping.

Comment: Also, boo hiss re: asking this here rather than SuperUser.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could also be on the Linux SE or Programmers too? Sometimes things aren't as clear cut as they should be.

Comment: Hmm. I'd lean towards SU myself -- it's not a programming-specific tool in any way, and neither is it Linux-specific (since GNU tools are pretty much everywhere). Unix SE, maybe.

Comment: Yet it is perfectly acceptable to ask questions about git itself on SO. It's just not clear at all where things should go sometimes.

Comment: Git is explicitly a programming tool. I mean, yes, it's a distributed filesystem if considered more abstractly, but the explicit target audience is software developers (initially, kernel developers).

Comment: (From the tour in the help center, at http://stackoverflow.com/tour: "Don't ask about [...] anything not directly related to writing computer programs").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you enter `/` in less, the following expression is a regex. As such, `*` has special meaning there; `/*` thus searches for zero-or-more instances of `/`.

To prevent any character from having special meaning, you can enter it as a character class:

```
/[/][*]
```

...ensures that both of the characters you're searching for are treated literally. This works in other regular-expression contexts (grep, etc) as well.

---

That said, the above is somewhat more paranoid than necessary. In my tests, the below work as well:

```
//[*]
//\*
```

Comment: Are backslashes not applicable here or do they add more chaos to the madness?

Comment: The backslashes should work -- I can't reproduce the case where they don't (with less 418 or 458). That said, I tend to prefer the character-class approach simply because it's less error-prone: There are several situations where backslashes can be destroyed by unintended unescaping.

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing from [this fine answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430576/6662), after you press `/` to start the search, you can press Ctrl + R to disable regexes.

This is great if you want to paste in a long string full of special characters to search for and don't want to have to go through escaping each one by hand!